# Drupal 7 - Giving correct path to callback function in #autocomplete_path

Tags: forms, ajax, routes

I have this below code for autocomplete implementation but I just get AJAX error

[image]

As you can see there is not anymore details for tracking down the issue. I also checked the logs but seems like this particular error is not logged anywhere which is making me hard to debug. However I suspect (almost confirmed) there is a strong relation between menu path (`tdyards/tdyards_searchbox`), autocomplete_path (`tdyards/tdyards_searchbox/autocomplete_callback`)and callback function name (`tdyards_searchbox_autocomplete_callback`)

Please help me to understand and correct this

Below is the complete code of my module which is sub-module of tdyards

```
function tdyards_searchbox_menu(){

  $items['tdyards/tdyards_searchbox'] = array(
    'title' => 'Autocomplete (simple)',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('autocomplete_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
    ); 

  return $items;

}
function autocomplete_form($form, &$form_state) {


  //dpm(cities_autocomplete_callback("A"));
  $form['info'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div>' . t("This example does a simplest possible autocomplete by username. You'll need a few users on your system for it to make sense.") . '</div>',
  );

  $form['user'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Choose a user (or a people, depending on your usage preference)'),
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'tdyards/tdyards_searchbox/autocomplete_callback',
  );

  return $form;
}

function tdyards_searchbox_autocomplete_callback($string = "") {

  return drupal_json_output(drupal_map_assoc(array('Data','Theta','Quota','Meta')));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just forgotten to define the path for the autocomplete itself:

```
function tdyards_searchbox_menu(){

  $items['tdyards/tdyards_searchbox'] = array(
    'title' => 'Autocomplete (simple)',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('autocomplete_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
    ); 

  $items['tdyards/tdyards_searchbox/autocomplete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Autocomplete',
    'page callback' => 'tdyards_searchbox_autocomplete_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;

}
```

Add that, clear the caches, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your #autocomplete_path needs to point to a menu callback, so you'd have something like this

```
function hook_menu() {
  // autocomplete_path menu item
  $items['tdyards/tdyards_searchbox/autocomplete_callback'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'tdyards_searchbox_autocomplete_callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
  );
}
```

..

```
// automcomplete menu item callback function
function tdyards_searchbox_autocomplete_callback($string = "") {
  return drupal_json_output(drupal_map_assoc(array('Data','Theta','Quota','Meta')));
}
```

If you are passing in arguments you can add % wildcard to the path and set 'page arguments' => array(1)

Comment: missing 'access arguments', without this the form is not rendered as autocomplete text field

Comment: Hey yes probably, it was just to let you know you needed a menu item for the #auto_complete